# Google Datalab: How to put the code on a trigger/CRON to run daily

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I'm new to Datalab. 
After going through the Quickstart and much of documentation, I still cannot figure out what to do if I want to **run a notebook automatically** e.g. once a day.

Can you please help

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Datalab does not offer an out of box solution to running notebooks automatically on a schedule. If you're willing to write some code to automate running a notebook, you can take a look at the test script for the [Datalab notebooks repository here](https://github.com/googledatalab/notebooks/blob/master/.test.sh). This uses `jupyter nbconvert` to run notebooks, and you can easily run this script on a schedule.